# Halcon - Move XLD line

Tags: line, move, halcon

I have a Iconic variable `BackWallBoundaryLineXLD`
It containts 2 points and the line connecting them.

I would need to move this line upwards 40 pixels, so basically change the row coordinate of the line to Currentvalue-40.

Is there a simple and clean way to do it, or do I have to extract the points first, edit them and then draw a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
hom_mat2d_identity (HomMat2DIdentity)
hom_mat2d_translate (HomMat2DIdentity, -40, 0, HomMat2DTranslate)
affine_trans_contour_xld (BackWallBoundaryLineXLD, BackWallBoundaryLineXLDTranslated, HomMat2DTranslate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  affine_trans_contour_xld(). You will have to setup a HomMat3D first that specifies your 40pixel translation.

Comment: uhm... sounds complex.. Ill read into it and try.. thank you